# Is there a way to prevent Enabled="false" / disabled="disabled" being changed in the browser via Inspect Element?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, security

If I have a selection of options on a page and one of them is disabled via the code behind, it is rendered in the browser as:

**aspx**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="myRadioButton" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="myMethod_Click" AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" />
```

**html**

```
<input id="myRadioButton" type="radio" name="myRadioButton" value="1" disabled="disabled">
```

However a user who knows what they're doing can re-enable the control via the browsers Inspect Element functionality, and exploit the option.

How can avoid this while still displaying the control?

Comment: Validate *all* data from the browser server-side. All of it, every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript. You can set an interval to check every say fifty miliseconds if it's not disabled and if it's not you can change it back to disabled. You will have to use JavaScript for this.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("myRadioButton").getAttribute("disabled") !== "disabled"){
        document.getElementById("myRadioButton").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}, 50);
```